# C++ Unordered Pair Type

Tags: c++, std-pair

I'd like to create an unordered pair type in c++, that is, an `unordered_set` guaranteed to have exactly two elements. Here's what I've come up with, but the problem is if I use this approach, there's a heck of a lot more I have to override - each of the comparison operators, and so on. Is there a simpler way?

```
class unordered_pair : public std::pair<t, u>
{
public:
    unordered_pair(t x, u y) : std::pair<t, u>(x,y) {};
    bool operator ==(const unordered_pair<t,u>& rhs)
    {
        if ((this->first < this->second) ^ (rhs.first < rhs.second))
        {
            return this->second == rhs.first && this->first == rhs.second;
        }
        else
        {
            return this->first == rhs.first && this->second == rhs.second;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Are `t` and `u` fixed types?

Comment: No, but if it's easier, you can assume t == u

Comment: Do you want to be able to change `x` and `y` after construction or is your type non-mutable (except from copy/move-assignments)?

Comment: I thought about making these immutable objects, that certainly makes the problem a lot easier.

Comment: Can you guarantee that the operator `^` is valid for all types?  For example, if I create an `unordered_pair<std::string, char *>`, the `operator ^` is not valid for a `std::string` type (since a `std::string` is a container).  Also, the `operator^` is not really applicable to floating point.

Comment: I'd go a different route - you say it's "unordered" but then you try and keep the order...  if you don't care about order, then use that to your advantage.  I'd always sort the pair so that the first is smaller than the second - this way (5, 10) and (10, 5) will end up being stored in the same way; and no operators need to be overloaded; unless you want to sort them automatically when attempting to perform an =,< etc.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews yes, you can... if it's not the compiler will barf :)  (In the same way that trying to use a std::map without the operator < will result in bad things)

Comment: @UKMonkey If you do so, you need to guarantee that the two members stay ordered, which you cannot if you inherit from `std::pair` publicly, and if you don't, you need to implement all comparison operators.

Comment: @ukmonkey that's what I was afraid of, that if I don't implement < well map will do bad things, which opens the door to anything. I think you're right, assignment is the right way to go.

Comment: @Holt "If you do so, you need to guarantee that the two members stay ordered," that's exactly the guarantee I'm suggesting to break.  If order is required, then not only is this class very strange to start with, but a getter for the original pair could be provided. No need to override any operators. Let me throw an answer up to clarify

Comment: @UKMonkey I don't follow you, you said *"I'd always sort the pair so that the first is smaller than the second - this way (5, 10) and (10, 5) will end up being stored in the same way"*, so basically you want your constructor to order the values, but if you do so, you need to implement all operators, or you'd have to do `up.get_pair() == up2.get_pair()` each time you want to compare them?

Comment: @Holt I think my answer explains better than my comments :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do something like

```
struct unordered_pair : std::pair<t, u>
{
    bool swapped;

    unordered_pair(t x, u y) : 
        std::pair<t, u>(x,y),
        swapped(false);
    {
        sort();
    }

    void sort() {
        swapped = first > second;
        if (swapped)
            std::swap(first, second);
    }

    std::pair<t, u> getOrig() {
        if (swapped)
            return std::pair<t,u>(second, first);
        return std::pair<t, u>(first, second);
    }
}
```

Then you just call sort() every time you change first or second; and all the comparison operators are obtained from the std::pair for free!

The motivation is that if you don't care about the ordering for comparisons, then you won't care about the ordering most of the time; Which will mean most of the time, you won't need to get the original item.

Edit:  You state in the comments that we can assume t==u ... in that case I would suggest getting rid of t or u - and make it just `std::pair<t, t>`

Comment: I think this is the right approach - keep them ordered on assignment or update.

Comment: That does mean that all the users need to know to call `sort()` if either element has been modified (e.g. through the references returned by `get()`).

Comment: @TobySpeight yes - there's no fix to this since std::pair doesn't offer getter/setter on first & second.  It's not perfect - but it means that (for example) the comparison operators could be overridden to just assert that they ARE sorted - which is much simpler than trying to re-implement all the operators to deal with unsorted data.

Comment: @rmawatson one more on construction, but one less on every other comparison operation - it's a gain depending on the use case   "and it only works if they're the same time" well ... that's the requirements.  "you can assume t == u"

Answer (score 2):

Let's fill in some types into this template (which you omitted the `template`, there is no declaration of `t` or `u`), and see what it tries to instantiate

```
unordered_pair<int, std::string> pair, pair2;

bool operator ==(const unordered_pair<t,u>& rhs)
{
    if ((this->first < this->second) ^ (rhs.first < rhs.second))
```

This is `bool operator <(int, std::string)` and `bool operator <(std::string, int)`. These don't exist.

```
    {
        return this->second == rhs.first && this->first == rhs.second;
    }
```

This is `bool operator ==(int, std::string)` and `bool operator ==(std::string, int)`. These also don't exist.

```
    else
    {
        return this->first == rhs.first && this->second == rhs.second;
    }
}
```

You instead want *one* template type parameter. Try something like this

```
class bad_unordered_pair : public std::exception
{
    const char * what() const { return "unordered_pair must have exactly two distinct values"; }
}

template <typename T>
std::pair<T, T> make_unordered_pair(T first, T second)
{
    std::hash<T> hash;
    if (first == second) throw bad_unordered_pair{};
    if (hash(first) < hash(second)) return unordered_pair(first, second);
    return unordered_pair(second, first);
}
```

Comment: Using `unordered_set` to store two values is likely a bad idea, if you want to store a vector of them, you'd have multiple indirections with dynamic allocation everywhere for such a simple type.

Comment: I think OP mentioned `unordered_set` for the behavior, not for the actual implementation, otherwise, he would have used it.

Answer (score 1):

**Aside**: I'm assuming that you meant

```
template<typename t>
class unordered_pair : public std::pair<t, t>
```

since it doesn't make sense for the members to be of different types if they should be interchangeable.

---

You could write a simple `sorted()` method, to ease writing these overloads:

```
private:
    std::tuple<t const&, t const&> ordered() const noexcept
    {
        return (this->first < this->second)
            ? std::tie(this->first, this->second)
            : std::tie(this->second, this->first);
    }
};
```

Then implement `==` and `<` using that:

```
bool operator ==(const unordered_pair<t>& rhs) const noexcept
{
    return ordered() == rhs.ordered();
}
bool operator <(const unordered_pair<t>& rhs) const noexcept
{
    return ordered() < rhs.ordered();
}
```

and the other operators in terms of those:

```
bool operator !=(const unordered_pair<t>& rhs) const noexcept
{
    return !(*this == rhs);
}

bool operator >(const unordered_pair<t>& rhs) const noexcept
{
    return rhs < *this;
}

bool operator <=(const unordered_pair<t>& rhs) const noexcept
{
    return !(rhs < *this);
}

bool operator >=(const unordered_pair<t>& rhs) const noexcept
{
    return !(*this < rhs);
}
```

---

Alternatively, if you have C++20, then implement `<=>` instead:

```
template<typename T>
class unordered_pair : public std::pair<T, T>
{
public:
    unordered_pair(T x, T y)
        : std::pair<T, T>(x,y)
    {}

    std::strong_ordering operator<=>(const unordered_pair<T>& other)
    {
        return ordered() <=> other.ordered();
    }

private:
    std::tuple<T const&, T const&> ordered() const noexcept
    {
        return (this->first < this->second)
            ? std::tie(this->first, this->second)
            : std::tie(this->second, this->first);
    }
};
```

Or even absorb the helper into the operator:

```
std::strong_ordering operator<=>(const unordered_pair<T>& other)
{
    auto ordered = [](unordered_pair<T> const& t) {
        return (t.first < t.second)
        ? std::tie(t.first, t.second)
        : std::tie(t.second, t.first);
    };

    return ordered(*this) <=> ordered(other);
}
```

---

Whichever approach you take, you'll want to be careful not to compare through base-class pointers, or you'll get inconsistent behaviour.